# setting up and running apache nutch 2.2.1

Tags: apache, hbase, nutch, gora

I am trying to set up and run apache nutch 2.2.1 on my ubuntu desktop. As a newbie, I found some parts of the tutorial given by the official website a bit confusing.

1. If I were to run it on my own desktop, is it correct to go to the

   ```
   $NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local
   ```

to run the bin/nutch command?

2. Where should I put the file named urls? (in which there a seed list seed.txt) Is it under

   ```
   $NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local
   ```

If I am in the right directory, I had this problem executing the command

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 1
```

InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.memory.store.MemStore as the Gora storage class.
InjectorJob: total number of urls rejected by filters: 0
InjectorJob: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=generate: null, jobid=job_local1613558008_0002
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:54)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:199)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.runTool(Crawler.java:68)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:152)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.main(Crawler.java:257)

I am following the tutorial 1 http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial until 3.3
and have yet to configure GORA Hbase etc. 
It seems that this problem arises because the injector did not get the urls. 
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: For Nutch 2.2.1 you have to follow the tutorial for Nutch 2.x: http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should go to `$NUTCH_HOME/runtime/deploy`  to run the command

Answer (score -1):

in case you want integrate with GORA and Hbase mention this in Nutchsite.xml

```
 <property>
        <name>storage.data.store.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore</value>
        <description>Default class for storing data</description>
    </property>
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're suggesting or which part of the question you are answering here, could you edit this answer to give more detail?